# "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 1: invalid continuation byte" - aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, utf-8, base64

I am trying to decode a JSON formatted mqtt message that is sent to an aws lamda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   eventText = event['data']
   eventText = base64.b64decode(eventText)
   s2 = eventText.decode("UTF-8")
```

It seems that no matter the input message I receive this error:
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1: invalid start byte"

For example the above error was generated with:

```
{
"data": "Random Text=="
}
```

The value of event['data'] is "Random Text==" and the value of base64.b64decode(eventText) is "b'E\xa9\xdd\xa2d\xde\xc6'"

I am not familiar with these encoding protocols any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the *exact* value `event['data']`?  "Random Text" does not have a 0xdb byte in it.

Comment: I discovered a padding issue and changed my input message slightly which also changed the byte the error is referring to, I edited my question and included the value of event['data']

Comment: That "Random Text==" value seems like a placeholder.  Base64-encoded data is unlikely to look like that.  The decoded result is *definitely* not UTF-8-encoded text.

Comment: It's likely that the data is compressed. If it doesn't contain sensitive information, please update your question with the _exact_ value of `data`. Also, what is invoking this event? IoT Core, or something else?

Comment: If it is sensitive, it should be OK to post the first 8 characters, which should be enough to identify any encoding, but not expose sensitive details (8 characters translates to 6 bytes of data).

Answer (score 0):

I've realized with the help of your comments that I misunderstood the code I was editing, the message that was currently being sent was not encoded so there was no reason to decode it.

Comment: Since this is something that only applies to you, I suggest that you delete the question.